# java-hadoop using virtualbox -- no output

Tags: java, hadoop, virtualbox

this is my code

```
public class solution1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String localStr = args[0];
    String hdfsStr = args[1];

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem hdfs  = FileSystem.get(URI.create(hdfsStr), conf);
    FileSystem local = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

    Path inputDir = new Path(localStr);
    String folderName = inputDir.getName(); 
    Path hdfsFile = new Path(hdfsStr, folderName);

    try {
        FileStatus[] inputFiles = local.listStatus(inputDir);
        FSDataOutputStream out = hdfs.create(hdfsFile);

        for (int i=0; i<inputFiles.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(inputFiles[i].getPath().getName());
            FSDataInputStream in = local.open(inputFiles[i].getPath());
            byte buffer[] = new byte[256];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while( (bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

i am trying to use this code to loop through hundreds of .txt file
this the the content of the .txt files, and there are 500 of this
[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h16yC.jpg)

**updated**

this is what i typed in virtual box and this is the result i get, the output is not the expected output, no successful result
[no successful result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKm3m.png)

**it is not reading the content inside individual txt file**

but if i were to use the same command to run another java file, there is a result, it will run successfully. it looks like this
[this is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cricJ.jpg)

the code for wordcount java is here

```
public class WordCount {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }
}
```

i am stuck and cannot really figure out how to proceed. what should i type in virtualbox for my code to read all 500 txt files?

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information. Also see [ask].

Comment: ...only partially though...

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do with the way you run your Hadoop job. Why are you putting a Java program as the input of your MR job? If I get it right, you should put your directory with 500 txt files in HDFS and put the name of it as the first argument instead of ``solution1.java`. Can you explain us what you are trying to do, and what the desired output would be?

Comment: @Coursal thank you for pointing that out. did i put it correctly this time? i am required to compile a Java solution1.java and create a jar file, and use to it to process the files in
FewFiles (which is the file with 500 txt files)

Comment: The `solution1.java` program just reads and prints the _names_ of the files in a directory given as input, while their contents are stored in a directory in HDFS (you will see the results within HDFS in `/user/output` as you specified, not on the local filesystem). For the second screenshot, you could just run `$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar WordCount.jar WordCount /user/output`, although I don't know if this can read the data in `/user/output` because everything will be kinda glued together in one file

Comment: @Coursal  i see, thank you for your help. i do understand now. thank you!